# Express $e^x$ in terms of $\sinh x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, hyperbolic-functions

Given
$$
\sinh x = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}
$$
how can I express $e^x$ in terms of $\sinh x$? I get
$$
e^x = \sqrt{1 + 2e^x\sinh x}
$$
where I can't get rid of $e^x$ on the right hand side.

Comment: What is wrong with the formula you already have?   $\sinh x = \frac{y}{2} - \frac{1}{2y}$ where $y=e^x$.

Comment: I didn't see the quadratic, thanks!

Comment: If you mean to ask for an expression for $e^x$ in terms of $\sinh x$, then Teresa's comment is the way to go.  If you really want an expression for $\sinh x$ in terms of $e^x$, it seems like the definition already is one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $e^x = y$, then $y-\frac 1y = 2 \sinh x$, followed by $y^2 - 2y \sinh x - 1 = 0$.

Using the quadratic formula,
$$
e^x = y = \sinh x \pm \sqrt{(\sinh x)^2+1}
$$
However, as $e^x>0$, the $-$ sign cannot happen. Hence, we have $$
e^x = \sinh x + \sqrt{(\sinh x)^2+1}
$$

Comment: Should be $2y \sinh x$ in the quadratic equation.

Comment: It's $y^2-2y\sinh x-1=0$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\cosh x=(e^x+e^{-x})/2$ you can "cheat" and write $$e^x=\sinh x+\cosh x.$$
Also these obey rules similar to sines and cosines, except for signs, for example $\cosh^2 x-\sinh^2 x=1$, so $\cosh x=\sqrt{\sinh^2 x+1}$, so we also have
$$
e^x=\sinh x + \sqrt{\sinh^2 x+1}.
$$
Incidentally this gives us the formula
$$
\sinh^{-1}y=\log\left(y+\sqrt{y^2+1}\right).
$$